# Accounts.onCreateUser clean up my code

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

When a new user account is created I'm using the Accounts.onCreateUser function to insert data into a new collection. I want to check that the insert has successfully worked before progressing. My code appears to work however it seems very messy. I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to write this code.

```js
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  if (user) {
    CandidateProfile.insert({
      userId: user._id,
      firstName: options.profile.name.first,
      lastName: options.profile.name.last
    });

    var checkForNewCandidateProfile = CandidateProfile.findOne(
      { userId: user._id },
      { fields: { userId: 1 } }
    );
    var userId =
      checkForNewCandidateProfile && checkForNewCandidateProfile.userId;

    if (userId === user._id) {
      return user;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: i'm a little surprised that works. afaik, insert is an async operation, and you're doing a read from the collection immediately therefafter. i would have suspected that the findOne() doesn't find anything. i'm really curious how that's working. regardless, by conditionally returning user, are you saying you want the registration to fail if the write to your collection fails?

Comment: It already fails when something goes wrong with the insert and on the client side the user see's an `internal server error appear`. The logs display a full error. You said you're surprised it works, that's my question, what is the correct way to write this?

Comment: it's possible that Futures may work in this context to provide a sync-like experience, since onCreateUser() is meant to work synchronously. check out my answer here for what that might look like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43564544/3199246

Comment: Hey @zim, could you tell me how insert is an async operation? Any reference?

Comment: @bp123 could you paste the error logs?

Comment: @zim On the server `insert` runs synchronously, callback is optional.

Comment: @RamilMuratov thanks for pointing that out. i thought it was async.

Comment: @MohammadKashifSulaiman, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I don't see any sense in your test. You don't trust `insert`?

But OK, you need it.

1. Be sure, that you run your code on the server side. Import it only on server side or just wrap it in `if (Meteor.isServer)`
2. Why check if `user` arg exists? It is, that's how that callback works.
3. If something's wrong, throw an error to abort user creation.

Possible variant:

```js
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
    // You insert sync, so it's up to you to handle errors.
    try {
      CandidateProfile.insert({
        userId: user._id,
        firstName: options.profile.name.first,
        lastName: options.profile.name.last
      });

      var checkForNewCandidateProfile = CandidateProfile.findOne(
        { userId: user._id },
        { fields: { userId: 1 } }
      );
      var userId =
        checkForNewCandidateProfile && checkForNewCandidateProfile.userId;

      if (userId === user._id) {
        return user;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
    throw new Error("Something's wrong.");
  });
}
```

Comment: It's critical that the insert doesn't fail. I'm still new to coding. Is it not normal to check if an insert has worked?

Comment: It is quite normal. When you run something async you have a callback with error arg to handle errors. On the other hand, when you run something synchronously you can wrap it in `try`/`catch` to handle errors. I was not 100% correct about trusting `insert`. Nothing wrong with that, error may appear.